# Magento 2: How to set default store

Tags: magento2

I have a store in several languages.
When I enter website, an English-language store is displayed. How can I set the main language Polish after open website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

> Store -> All stores -> Click on poland store or your store -> change value of default store view dropdown

Select your store view which you want to display.

Answer (score 5):

just make this default also in Magento version is 2.3

For the newer version (my Magento version is 2.2.x). So, we could change the default store view:

**STORES > All Stores > Select Store**

[image]

[image]